# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:

Tags: java

In this program I am storing properties to the arraylist.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
Property property1 = new Property(24,"Boston Australia",3,45,67);

        Property property2 = new Property(24,"Boston Malvern",3,45,67);
        Property property3 = new Property(24,"Boston Caulfield",3,45,67);
        Property property4 = new Property(24,"Boston Caulfield",3,45,67);
        Property property5 = new Property(24,"Boston Caulfield",3,45,67);
        SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl sl;
        sl = new SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl();
        sl.addProperty(property1);
        sl.addProperty(property2);
        sl.addProperty(property3);
        sl.addProperty(property4);
        sl.addProperty(property5);
}
```

SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl has a method addProperty where I am adding the property object to the arraylist.

```
public class SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl implements PropertyRepository{
    ArrayList<Property> properties;

    public SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl(){
        properties = new ArrayList<>();

    }
    @Override
    public void addProperty(Property property) throws Exception {

         properties.add(property);


        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }
```

It is giving me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at fit5042.tutex.repository.SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl.addProperty(SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl.java:29)
    at fit5042.tutex.RealEstateAgency.main(RealEstateAgency.java:47)
```

Please help me understand why am I getting this exception when I am not using any unmodifiable set.

Comment: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` - The code does *exactly* what it was told to; and the exception trace says *exactly* where it was written - `..at SimplePropertyRepositoryImpl.addProperty..(line 29)`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the unconditional `throw` in `addProperty`. Something like,

```
public void addProperty(Property property) throws Exception {
     properties.add(property);
     // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

With the above `throw` not commented out, it will **always** `throw` that `UnsupportedOperationException`.